# How to add GL Transitions between two video streams in android?

Tags: android, transition, video-processing

I have a requirement to merge the list of videos and add gl transition while merging these videos together.

Here is the link https://github.com/alexiscn/MTTransitions sample code of applying transition between two video streams in iOS and I have to implement the same in android as well.

I have not found any solution currently, it would be a great help if anyone can suggest or share some links so that I can implement the same in Android.

Thank you so much in advance